# Even though I have an array of posts defined in Redux state map() function is not working on it

Tags: reactjs, arrays, redux, state

I have defined my posts as an array in my redux state but when I try to map it in component code it does not seem to work.
Here's my redux state code:

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    mode:"light",
    user:null,
    token:null,
    posts:[]
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name:"auth",
    initialState,
    reducers:{
        setMode: (state)=>{
            state.mode = state.mode === "light" ? "dark":"light"
        },
        setLogin: (state,action)=>{
            state.user  = action.payload.user;
            state.token = action.payload.token;

        },
        setLogout:(state)=>{
            state.user = null;
            state.token = null;
        },

        setFriends:(state,action)=>{
            if(state.user){
                state.user.friends = action.payload.friends
            }
            else{
                console.error("User friends non-exsistant")
            }

        },
        setPosts:(state,action)=>{
            state.posts = action.payload.posts;
        },
        setPost:(state,action)=>{
            const updatedPosts = state.posts.map((post)=>{
                if(post._id === action.payload.post_id) return action.payload.post;
                return post;
            });
            state.posts = updatedPosts;
        }
    }

 })

 export const {setMode , setLogin ,setLogout,setFriends,setPosts,setPost}= authSlice.actions;

 export default authSlice.reducer;
```

This is my component section code I have properly used `Useselector()` function to grab the posts array but still it gives error that `Map()` is not a function, I have also properly implemented Redux and wrapped my app in Provider tag.

```
const PostsWidget = ({ userId, isProfile = false }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector((state)=> state.posts);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.token);
```

```
Here is the map code

`return (
    <>
      {posts.map(
        ({
          _id,
          userId,
          firstName,
          lastName,
          description,
          location,
          picturePath,
          userPicturePath,
          likes,
          comments,
        }) => (
          <PostWidget
            key={_id}
            postId={_id}
            postUserId={userId}
            name={`${firstName} ${lastName}`}
            description={description}
            location={location}
            picturePath={picturePath}
            userPicturePath={userPicturePath}
            likes={likes}
            comments={comments}
          />
        )``
```

I was expecting it to work but don't know why its giving me an error.

Comment: can you attach the reducer?

Comment: @almogkashany i have attched it now please review question

Comment: can you attach also the index.ts ? where the App called

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting your question. It looks like you have a small typo in your code.

Your code:

```
if(post._id === action.payload.post_id) return action.payload.post;
```

Correct code:

```
if (post._id === action.payload.post._id) return action.payload.post;
```

Notice the dot before `_id`.

By the way, this was mentioned in the tutorial at 5:06:50: https://youtu.be/K8YELRmUb5o?t=18410

I hope this helps